# Will cross-domain scripting using JavaScript work when the two frames have the same domain 2 levels up?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain-policy

I have a scenario, in which a .net application is hosted from SAP portal.

- SAP portal domain: **portalURL.al.xx.company.com**
- App server domain: **AppURL.ss.xx.company.com**

As you can notice the portal and the app server domains are **not** same **1 level up**.(i.e. at 1 level up, portal domain will be al.xx.company.com & app server will be ss.xx.company.com).

However at **2 levels** up both the portal and app server domains are same. (i.e. xx.company.com).

In my JavaScript code, I have set the document.domain object to be **xx.company.com**.
However still I am getting '**permission denied**' error.

The protocol of both portal and appserver are same.

Will the cross domain scripting under same-origin law work only if the domains are same at 1 level up? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Same-Origin policy will deny this. The two frames have to be on the exact same domain, and even the same port.

However, `document.domain` *should* work around that. If it's not working for you, remember that you have to set `document.domain` to `xx.company.com` in *both frames* (and, if you're working your way up a hierarchy of other frames to get there (eg `top.frame2`) you'll need to set it for those other frames as well (`top`).

If you have access to all the code, though, it's possible that you can work around this with [JSON-P](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding)

Comment: Thanks. That sounds hopeful. In this case, the other frame in question is SAP portal. And the .Net App is trying to retrieve SAP objects like top.EPCM and methods like top.SetDirty(). Is it possible to set object.domain property at SAP side? I don't know if scripting is possible at SAP portal.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), try considering the [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).